# React not reaching static images in a Rails stack on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I have a rails app with react, I have a simple img tag in one of my components:

```
render: function(){
    return (
      <img src='/assets/avatar-50.png' alt='profile pic' className='img-circle' />
    )
}
```

This works in development, but in production the image is not available, what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: can you reach that image from the url. like your-domain.com/assets/avatar-50.png?  is the filename lowercased? do you precompile your assets locally? With `rake assets:precompile` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally and push again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you have not specified the version of rails you are using, but i would assume that it has asset-compilation with digests. so production image-urls will actually look different than in local development. that is why you need to use helper methods like `image_url` in order to reference them. read more about this topic in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Comment: I am using Rails 5, still a concern?

Comment: yes, its working the same way: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production